# Forcing Browser Refresh

Tags: javascript, html

When I use "a href=..." I would like the browser to reload the page from the server and not get it from the buffer.  Using the forward and back buttons to pull from the browser buffer is OK but not when it is a link on the page.

I know this is a question that has been ask several times.  It looks like a problem for many.  I have looked at many answers.  I find many out of date.  I find many others were never really answered.  I am beginning to wonder if it is even possible.

This question is mostly for web development purposes.  For now I can simply have the browser check if there is an updated every time the page is loaded. This is a feature in Internet Explorer and requires an extension in Chrome.  Kind of brute force.  There should be a more general solution.

I expect someone, somewhere has written a JavaScript for this but I cannot find it.

Comment: can you control the response headers?

Comment: Use AJAX, with proper `Cache-Control` set on the server, or use WebSockets if appropriate.

Comment: Append a random query parameter: `"?_t=" + Date.now()`?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Also, what you're referring to as a "buffer" is called the "cache".

Comment: Yes, I am using the term buffer and cache interchangeably.  I find many similar answers do this also.<br/><br/>This got marked duplicate.  In the orginal post I acknowledged that there were similar answers but many are out of date and do not work in current versions of browsers today.  Others had lots of comments but never answered the question.<br /><br />I tried the random parameter and dose not work.  It was noted in other answers and must be one of the many out of date solutions.<br /><br />I am looking for an answer that uses only HTML and JavaScript.  Not AJAX

Comment: It looks like your suggestion of adding <br /> is also out of date.  Is it possible to add line breaks to comments.